# Creation of System Topic failed while creating Event Subscription in Azure Maps

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-eventgrid, azure-maps

I keep getting the following error while creating **Event Subscription** for my **Azure Maps Account**.

**Error:**
*Creation of System Topic has failed with error: System topic's location must match with location of the source resource /subscriptions/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-a229d67dddf5/resourceGroups/rg-ets-new/providers/Microsoft.Maps/accounts/ets-maps-account. Event Subscription will not be created.*

I get the same error if I add an **Event Grid System Topic** of **Azure Maps Accounts Type** in the same resource group the Maps Account is in. The resource group and the maps account both have the same region (West Centeral US) assigned to them.

What do you think is going wrong here?  Any clues?

PS. The event subscriptions are working fine for other resources, Queues for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be an bug. We have reported it to Product teams. They are working on the fix. Meanwhile, there is an alternative to achieve the same.

We can successfully create an event grid topic with source events from an Azure Maps account by using Azure CLI, like in the below command. I have replaced any actual subscription details below with placeholders.

```
az eventgrid system-topic create --name topicName --location global --topic-type Microsoft.Maps.Accounts --source "/subscriptions/subscriptionName/resourceGroups/resourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.Maps/accounts/mapAccountName" --resource-group "resourceGroupName"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The azure cli alternative works fine. Hope they fix it in  azure portal as well.